# Write multiple rows at once to s3 in parquet format using sparkSession.createDataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am successfully creating a single frame/row and writing to s3 in parquet format using the following

```
data_for_frame = [{"Category": 'Category A', "ID": 1, "Value": Decimal(12.40)},
        {"Category": 'Category B', "ID": 2, "Value": Decimal(30.10)},
        {"Category": 'Category C', "ID": 3, "Value": Decimal(100.01)}
        ]


dynamic_frame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data_frame, schema_frame)
frame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data_frame, schema_frame)
frame.write.parquet(s3_path)
```

How can I write multiple rows at once to minimize writes every time ? Means I create multiple rows and somehow pass that one big frame to be written to s3 in one attempt
I have tried to put multiple frames into a list and then passed it to `frame.write` but that didn't work with error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'`

Also if I try to write to s3 in a loop with individual frames it errors out with

```
AnalysisException: 'path s3://stackoverflow-test-bucket/testing/default_bucket/year=2020/month=4/day=4 already exists.;'
```

Answer (score 1):

While trying to write in loop need to add `mode` as **`append`**.

- Default if spark found the `directory` that we are writing `exists` throws error
- We should select either **`append`**(adds new files into directory) (or) **`overwrite`**(drops and recreates directory) the directory.

---

```
frame.write.mode("append").parquet(s3_path)
```

Comment: Solves the second problem but still creates a new file file to append , it doesnt write to the same or first parquet file.